# Peer Command not found

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am working on this tutorial http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html

To Create and Join Channel i am trying to run following peer command :

```
peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ./channel-artifacts/channel.tx --tls $CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
```

I am connected to container as well after executing `docker exec -it cli` bash. Even i have tried `./peer` but i am still getting no peer directory exist or peer command not found

Comment: Can you please let us know the output from the following commands, run from within the cli container: 1) ls -l /usr/local/bin 2) echo $PATH

Comment: $ echo $PATH
/c/Users/lenovo/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/c/Program Files/D
ocker Toolbox:/c/Users/lenovo/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/min
gw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/lenovo/bin:/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_91/bin:/c/P
rogramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System
32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/
Phone:/cmd:/c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_pe
rl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl

Comment: lenovo@lenovo-PC MINGW64 ~/fabric-samples/first-network (release)
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/bin': No such file or directory

Comment: you must be INSIDE the cli container.

docker exec -it cli bash
root@de935c3ae296:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer#

Comment: yes i do get inside the container after running the docker exec -it ci bash @christo4ferris still facing the error peer command not found

Comment: actually, no, your 'ls' above was from the ~/fabric-samples/first-network directory. You are running Windows and hence would not have /usr/... on your filesystem.

Comment: So do i need to change path ? if yes then how ?

Comment: i have tried as following by changing path but still no luck : $ peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f C:\Users\
lenovo\fabric-samples\first-network\channel-artifacts\channel.tx --tls $CORE_PE
ER_TLS_ENABLED --cafile C:\Users\lenovo\fabric-samples\first-network\crypto-con
fig\ordererOrganizations\example.com\orderes\orderer.example.com\msp\tlscacerts
\tlsca.example.com-cert.pem
bash: peer: command not found

Comment: It isn't a matter of changing your path. You are not inside the container. If you run 'docker exec -it cli bash' that will enter the running container. If the container isn't running, then you need to start it, If you look inside the docker-compose-cli.yaml file you will see instructions to comment out the script that runs the tutorial automatically and this will allow you to enter the docker container with the above command.

Comment: @christo4ferris am able to enter into docker container successfully but i am not able to run the peer command as it hasn't not been able to find it

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to relative path is not correct, where peer binary is stored. You can find it inside hyperledger/fabric/build/bin. Once you locate the peer binary export it using.
e.g. export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/build/bin/

Then try to create channel using commands you are using.